# How to pass array to function as argument in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to map array element and return true or false if for example there is the summation of two numbers in my array equal 8.

bad way

```
function showNumbered(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            if(  arr[i] + arr[x] == 8 ) {
                console.log(true);
            }else{
                console.log(false);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, whats your question?

Comment: showNumbered([1,3,4,5,5])

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, it just logs messages.

Comment: Your code seems fine. You may consider using map() method for iterating over items instead of for loops

Comment: question :::: "How to pass array to function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sum of each with each number value in array.

If there is a sum that is equal to 8 returns `true` else return `false`

```js
var array = [3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 7];

function arrSum(arr) {
    var ret = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var ii = i+1; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[ii] === 8) {
                console.log(arr[i], '+', arr[ii], '=', true);
                ret = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(ret) { console.log(false); }
}

arrSum(array);
```

Comment: `&& i !== ii` why? Instead of three results, now you get two. However, the *correct* number of results is only one - there is a single pair of numbers sums to `8` in this code.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I wrote in my post why I'm doing this check. And at the moment I am looking for a solution to return the right number

Comment: Don't iterate through the entire length of the array twice. Once you've covered `0` to `i` you only need to check `i` to the length. Otherwise you'll be checking index `0` and `3` once then `3` and `0` later.

Comment: @VLAZ I think it happened now. Thank you very much!

Comment: // I fixed it with map operator thanks for all ------>
function showNumbered(arr) {
       arr.map(x => {
           arr.map(l => {
               if( x + l == 8 && x !== l){
                   console.log("true");
                   return true
                }
           })
       })
       return false;
}

console.log(showNumbered([1,2,5,8,9,2,6,7,1]));

Answer (score 0):

"how to pass array to function as argument"

```
function showNumbered(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            if(  arr[i] + arr[x] == 8 ) {
                console.log(true);
            }else{
                console.log(false);
            }
        }
    } 
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
showNumbered(arr)
```

you can do it in linary way. O(n)

```js
function showNumbered(arr, target) {
   const complementary = new Map(); 
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(complementary.has(arr[i])){ 
        console.log(complementary.get(arr[i]), i)
      } 
     complementary.set(target - arr[i], i)
   } 
}

showNumbered([1,3,5,6,8,3,4], 4)
```